# Mat-tab material angular6 selectedIndex doesn't work with *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I display several tabs with a loop ngFor using Angular Material tabs.
This works properly however now I would like to open the second tab when initialised and not the first tab.
Therefore, I add the property selectedIndex in the mat-tab-group but it doesn't work and still continues to open on the first tab.

**HTML**

```
<mat-tab-group class="col-10 offset-1" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)" [selectedIndex]="1">
  <mat-tab label={{tab.name}} *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index">
    <div>
      Values: {{tab.values}}
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The variable *"tabs"* is fetched with a service from the server in ngOnInit like this:

**COMPONENT**

```
this.api.getDataset(this.route.snapshot.params["experimentid"]).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.tabs = res;
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

I think it comes from here because if I set the tabs manually without requesting to the server it works. Like this:

```
this.tabs = [{name: "X2", values: "52"}, {name: "Z2", values: "52"}, {name: "R2", values: "52"}]
```

Comment: Try adding `*ngIf="tabs && tabs.length"` to your `mat-tab-group` component. See also example https://ng-run.com/edit/OxHxsmOQUgfxuH0grSra

Comment: @yurzui a much better solution than mine. It might not work if changing the tabs array from one set to another set.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the `selectedIndex` after your service data is available.  You need to do below changes:

1. Get hold of a reference to `MatTabGroup` instance in your component (the component whose template contains `mat-tab-group`) by declaring below attribute:

   ```
   @ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;
   ```
2. Then set the selectedIndex in `subscribe` method call while updating new value for `tabs`

   ```
   .subscribe(
     res => {
       this.tabs = res;
       this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = 1;
     },
   ```

Overall, you component may look somewhat like below:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTabGroup } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-basic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab-group-basic-example.css'],
})
export class TabGroupBasicExample implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

  tabs = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getDataset(experimentId).subscribe(
      res => {
          this.tabs = res;
          this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = 1;
      },
      err => {
          console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't answer it this way, because I thought `this.tabGroup.selectedIndex` would not trigger change detection inside the component. If you look at the source code in github the setter function does not trigger an update. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/tab-group.ts#L110

Answer (score 14):

`<mat-tab-group>` only reads the `[selectedIndex]` input when the component is first created. Afterwards the output binding `(selectedIndex)` lets you track tab changes.

I think you're setting the value `1` before that tab exists.

The problem is that `*ngFor` is creating the children `mat-tab` components afterwards. When `<mat-tab-group>` is notified that the children have changed it defaults to the *first* tab.

The only work-around that I know of is to trigger a change to the `[selectedIndex]` binding *after* the child `<mat-tab>` components have been created.

Update your component to have a property:

```
public selectedIndex: number = 0;
```

Use this as the binding for the selectedIndex input:

```
<mat-tab-group class="col-10 offset-1" 
               (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)" 
               [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
```

Inject these dependencies into your component:

```
  public constructor(private change: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Update your subscribe to change the selected index **after** the `*ngFor` has finished updating the document.

```
this.api.getDataset(this.route.snapshot.params["experimentid"]).subscribe(res => {
    this.tabs = res;
    // wait for ngFor to finish
    window.setTimeout(()=>{
       this.selectedIndex = 1;
       this.change.markForCheck();
    });
});
```

Comment: [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" and this.selectedIndex = 1; approach worked for me. Thanks.